# What is the difference between input and output in Embedded programming?

Tags: c, embedded

I'm learning embedded in school to program microcontrollers using C, i was wondering what the actual difference was between setting a pin on output vs input because i can't wrap my head around it, even though it sounds logical. I know I will be using the output register to send voltage to the pins but what will the input be used for then with an example? I guess it will be used to read output from the pins?

Comment: You don't "send voltage", you drive the output pin to a known state. Whereas input pins simply reads the voltage applied to see if it is above or below a certain threshold determined by hardware. This isn't really a programming question but an electronics one. The key to understanding this is to know how the GPIO hardware looks like.

Comment: To add to what Lundin said, the GPIO hardware differs between different micro controllers. I recommend you read the GPIO section of the reference manual of the controller you are using. In general "output" mode is some sort of push/pull configuration, "input" mode is some sort of pull-up/-down configuration.

Comment: This not a question about C programming as tagged.  It belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Clifford do you have the credentials to move it?

Comment: @TomV  Not to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ (AFAIK).  It is not listed as one of the five "sister" sites that a close vote may nominate.

Comment: You _set_ an output level high or low, whereas you _read_ an input level (which may also be high or low but externally asserted).  It seems me that that is kind of obvious form the natural language semantics of the words.  But possibly if English is not a first language, or electronics entirely new it is not as obvious as it seems to me?  So an input might for example read the state of a switch, whereas an output might be used to light an LED.

Comment: Sorry, should i move it or just leave it here? Thanks for the answers btw i get it now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments above show some more technical detail, this is a much simplified explanation which I hope will be more helpful to a beginner:

An input pin has a very high resistance.  This means that something else can decide what voltage it has.  The "something else" will be an output of some other device.

An output pin has a low resistance.  This means that it decides what the voltage is*.  That voltage can control something else.

Suppose you have a button and an LED light.  The button gets connected to an input on your microcontroller, the software can read "in" whether the button is pressed or released, depending on the voltage that the switch connects to.  Based on this, it can decide whether the LED should be on or off, and it then writes this "out" of an output pin, and the voltage there controls the LED.

`*` assuming you don't create a short-circuit by connecting it to something driving a different voltage.